# Visual Studio "The symbol has no implementations" when the assemblies are linked

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2019 and I'm currently attempting to step into a package that's linked in the project, but I keep getting "The symbol has no implementations". I understand what this means, but I'm not sure what's wrong here.

I have compiled a bunch of packages like so `dotnet pack -o C:/nupkgs` which all are higher version and are suffixed with `unfinshed001`.

Then these packages are installed onto a new project. However, when I attempt to step into the method that's part of the package, it says that it has no implementation. However, when I go to inspect the definition I see:

```
#region Assembly <package_name>, Version=14.1.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\<package_name>\14.1.11-unfinished001\lib\net5.0\<package_name>.dll
#endregion
```

Here's what I'm trying to step into:

```
        await repository.UpdateSequence(
            newPriorityList,
            originalPriorityList,
            auditContext.AccountId,
            cancellationToken);
```